# form is not submitting on 2nd ajax call

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

so i am working with jsf2.2 and primeface 3.5. 
I have a `h:form` with some input fields (`@viewScoped` backing beans) when i submit a form using `p:commandButton` (this button using ajax call), form is submitted successfully.

```
<p:tabView id="headOfAccountsId_tabview"
                                    onTabChange="mainHeadOfAccountsWidget_blockui.show();shoaWidget_blockui.show();mainHeadOfAccountsWidget_blockui.hide();shoaWidget_blockui.hide();">
                                    <!-- **************************************** Starting Main Head Of Accounts ******************************************* -->
                                    <p:tab title="Main Head Of Accounts" id="mainHeadOfAccountsId_tab">
                                        <p:blockUI block=":#{p:component('mainHeadOfAccountsId_tab')}"
                                            widgetVar="mainHeadOfAccountsWidget_blockui">
                                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                                        </p:blockUI>
                                        <h:form styleClass="form" id="mainHeadOfAccountsId_form">
                                            <fieldset class="generalFieldSet">
                                                <legend class="generalLegend">Main head of accounts</legend>
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnLabel">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="Select Section: "
                                                                    for="sectionId_selectbox" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="sectionId_selectbox"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.sectionBean.sectionIdBean}"
                                                                    required="true" requiredMessage="Select Section">
                                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Click here"
                                                                        itemValue="" />
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.sectionBean.sectionBeanMap}" />
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnLabel borderLeft_td">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="Select Estt:/Maint: "
                                                                    for="esttOrMaintId_selectbox" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu id="esttOrMaintId_selectbox"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMaintenanceEstablishmentBean.budgetMaintenanceEstablishmentIdBean}"
                                                                    required="true"
                                                                    requiredMessage="Select Estt:/Maint">
                                                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Click here"
                                                                        itemValue=" " />
                                                                    <f:selectItems
                                                                        value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMaintenanceEstablishmentBean.budgetMaintEsttMapBean}" />
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnLabel borderLeft_td">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="Enter Main Account Name: " />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField">
                                                                <p:inputText id="mainHeadOfAccountNameId_inputtext"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.mainHeadOfAccountNameBean}"
                                                                    required="true"
                                                                    requiredMessage="Enter main head of account name please">
                                                                    <f:validator validatorId="stringIsAllowed" />
                                                                    <f:validator validatorId="blankOrNullNotAllowed" />
                                                                </p:inputText>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnLabel borderLeft_td">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="Code (optional): " />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField">
                                                                <h:inputText id="mainHeadOfAccountCodeId_inputtext"
                                                                    size="6" maxlength="6"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.mainHeadOfAccountCodeBean}"
                                                                    required="true"
                                                                    requiredMessage="Enter Code Please">
                                                                </h:inputText>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnLabel">
                                                                <h:outputLabel value="Remarks: " />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField" colspan="0">
                                                                <h:inputText
                                                                    id="mainHeadOfAccountRemarksId_inputtext"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.mainHeadOfAccountRemarksBean}" />
                                                                <h:inputText style="display:none;"
                                                                    id="budgetMainHeadOfAccountId_inputtext"
                                                                    value="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.budgetMainHeadOfAccountsBean.budgetMainHeadOfAccountIdBean}" />
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="panelColumnField"></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="8" align="left">
                                                                <table cellspacing="5">
                                                                    <tbody>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td align="right">
                                                                                <p:commandButton value="Add"
                                                                                    update=":#{p:component('allMhoaId_messages')} :#{p:component('sectionId_selectbox')} :#{p:component('mainHeadOfAccountNameId_inputtext')} :#{p:component('mainHeadOfAccountCodeId_inputtext')} :#{p:component('mainHeadOfAccountRemarksId_inputtext')} :#{p:component('allMainHeadOfAccountsId_table')} :#{p:component('mhoaId_selectbox_shoa')}"
                                                                                    action="#{budgetHeadOfAccountsAction.addMainHeadOfAccountsOnAjax}"
                                                                                    onstart="mainHeadOfAccountsWidget_blockui.show();"
                                                                                    oncomplete="mainHeadOfAccountsWidget_blockui.hide();" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td align="left">
                                                                                <p:commandButton value="Reset"
                                                                                    type="button"
                                                                                    update="mainHeadOfAccountsId_form"
                                                                                    onclick="resetForm('#{p:component('mainHeadOfAccountsId_form')}');" />
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="center" colspan="8">
                                                                <p:messages id="allMhoaId_messages"
                                                                    styleClass=".ui-messages-error"
                                                                    autoUpdate="false" closable="true" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </h:form>
```

// data table



// different functionality here no need of this to post here

after updating form(`update="@form"`) when i again submit same form (without refreshing page) nothing happens, can any one makes me understand what is the actual problem?

Comment: Post more of your view here. Do you have nested `<h:form/>`s?

Comment: Can you post the complete xhtml page?

Comment: i have updated code please see above!